# How to disable fields that are pre-filled in WooCommerce checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, readonly

I would like to prevent (make these fields readonly, for example) users from changing their billing information on the WooCommerce checkout form.

I'm currently using this code snippet:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'mycustom_woocommerce_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
function mycustom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields)
{
   $fields['billing_first_name']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
   $fields['billing_last_name']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
   $fields['billing_email']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
   $fields['billing_phone']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
   return $fields;
}
```

**But the problem is:** If the user has not filled in any of these fields in the registration, he is unable to insert his data in the checkout form because these fields are not editable.

**My question is:**
If the fields are not empty, how to make them readonly (or disabled)

Someone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of 7uc1f3r certainly works getting the user data… But since WooCommerce 3, you can use [`WC_Checkout` `get_value()` dedicated method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Checkout.html#_get_value) as follow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'filter_wc_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
function filter_wc_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    // On checkout and if user is logged in
    if ( is_checkout() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // Define your key fields below
        $keys_fields = ['billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_email', 'billing_phone'];

        // Loop through your specific defined fields
        foreach ( $keys_fields as $key ) {
            // Check that a value exist for the current field
            if( ( $value = WC()->checkout->get_value($key) ) && ! empty( $value ) ) {
                // Make it readonly if a value exist
                $fields[$key]['custom_attributes'] = ['readonly'=>'readonly'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

If you want this code to be also active in My account > Addresses > edit…, you will just have to remove `is_checkout() &&` from the first **`IF`** statement.

Comment: Thank you Loic. At first, it's working perfectly. I will put it on the live site and test if users can place orders without problems.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for, comment with explanation added in code

```php
function mycustom_woocommerce_billing_fields( $fields ) {   
    // Get current user
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    // User id
    $user_id = $user->ID;

    // User id is found
    if ( $user_id > 0 ) { 
        // Fields
        $read_only_fields = array ( 'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_email', 'billing_phone' );

        // Loop
        foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {     
            if( in_array( $key, $read_only_fields ) ) {
                // Get key value
                $key_value = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true);

                if( strlen( $key_value ) > 0 ) {
                    $fields[$key]['custom_attributes'] = array(
                        'readonly'=>'readonly'
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

   return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'mycustom_woocommerce_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
```